# Page-object with known quantity of generated fields

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I'm using `Ruby`, `Watir-webdriver` and the `Page-object gem` at work for automated testing.

Just wondering how people would approach a page that was dynamic in nature in terms of quantity of text fields.  The page I'm currently working has `'key' / 'value'` pair list, with the ability to add as many as you want.

I know I could just access say the 5th one with something like

```
text_field(:key5, id: "key", index: 4)
text_field(:value5, id: "value", index: 4)
```

But it feels a bit messy populating a support page with a load of items that might not exist.

Is there a better approach to this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest idea that comes to mind is to do something like this:

```
text_fields(:key, :id => 'key')
text_fields(:value, :id => 'value')
```

This will generate the methods `key_elements` and `value_elements` which will return an array of the text fields.  Perhaps this will work for you.